# Replace src of an image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a website and based on language `en, sq or el,` I want to change image source. So I have a folder named screenshots then there are three folders: `en , sq and el`.

For example the URL for a picture named 'slide-phone.png' is:

```
img/screenshots/en/slide-phone.png
img/screenshots/sq/slide-phone.png
img/screenshots/el/slide-phone.png
```

On the html text I have a prameter : `{{ _('en') }}` that can have one of those value: `en , sq and el`. In this case is en.

```
<html lang="{{ _('en') }}">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  img_url = 'img/screenshots/'+"{{ _('en') }}"+'/slide-phone.png';
  console.log("img is:" , img_url);
  $('#slide-phone-img').attr('src',img_url);
</script>
```

The HTML div is like this:

```
 <img  id="slide-phone-img" src="" >
```

The console gives the right link: `img is: img/screenshots/en/slide-phone.png` but the src attribute is empty!

Why is happening this, I don't get it, can someone help me?

Comment: try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... your code here ... });`

Comment: I think the prefered method to set attributes is to use `prop` see example below. `attr()` also works fine.

Answer (score 6):

As per my comment, you need to wrap the code in `$(document).ready();` closure.

Working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// When document is loaded
$(document).ready(function()
{
    img_url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/logos/doodles/2016/st-davids-day-2016-5676738174517248-hp.jpg';
    $('#slide-phone-img').prop('src', img_url);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img  id="slide-phone-img" src="" >
</body>
</html>
```

Note: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) (why im using `prop`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur comment! I have an additional question if you can answer. I tried also another way of urls  but it's not working ,if I use this kind of URLs: $('#slide-phone-img').attr('src',{{ url_for('static', filename = img_url) }}); if we consider another folder static that contains img folder. Why is the src blank?

Comment: Most likely the function `url_for` is not returning the desired value. Why don't you console log it to make sure it's returning image uri?

Comment: Looks like you are using laravel/blade templating engine by using `{{ .. }}`. By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax: `$('#slide-phone-img').attr('src', {{! url_for('static', filename = img_url) !}});` - see documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

Comment: the img_url value is this: img/screenshots/en/slide-phone.png.
But the link using url_for gives this : http://0.0.0.0:5002/static/

Comment: @ Latheesan I'm using python and jinja

Comment: After using ! i got an error:  TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'!' at 269

Comment: If you are using `python` and `jinja`, then ignore my remarks, they are for `Laravel` & `Blade` engine. You should post this issue as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Just get html attribute "lang" value and change image src according to that value.

```
    $(document).ready(function(e){
       var language = $('html').attr('lang');
     if(language == "en"){
        var img_src = "img/screenshots/en/slide-phone.png";
        $('#slide-phone-img').attr('src',img_src);
     }
     else if(language == "sq"){
         var img_src = "img/screenshots/sq/slide-phone.png";
        $('#slide-phone-img').attr('src',img_src);
     }
     else{
          var img_src = "img/screenshots/el/slide-phone.png";
        $('#slide-phone-img').attr('src',img_src);
     }
  });
```

Comment: glad to help.@TinMat

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your script once the document is ready.  For example by wrapping it in a `$(document).ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    img_url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/logos/doodles/2016/st-davids-day-2016-5676738174517248-hp.jpg';
    $('#slide-phone-img').attr('src', img_url);
});
```